# Envio de Form HTML

Tags: html, formulário

Olá boa tarde estou com duvidas de como enviar as informações do meu formulário para um email , alguem poderia me ajudar indicar alguma coisa que eu possa fazer , obrigado !! Abraços

Abaixo tem uma imagem de como esta o formulário o codigo CSS e HTML.
 [image: Formulário]

```css
#topo {
 background:url(../imagens/topo2etrelas2.png);
 border-left:1px solid #000;
 border-right:1px solid #000; 
 position:inherit;
 width:1024px;
 height:190px;
 margin:auto;
 

}

#fundoinicial {
 background: #FFF;
 width: 1024px;
 height: 500px;
 margin: auto;
 position:relative;
 border-right: 1px solid #000;
 border-left: 1px solid #000;
 
}


#menufundo {
 background:#60365e;
 border:1px solid #000;
 position:relative;
 width:1024px;
 height:28px;
 margin:auto;
  
}


#ul li a{
 font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-style:normal;
 list-style-type:none;
 display: inline;
 font-size:19px;
 line-height:0px;
 padding:10px;
    margin:4px 0 0 52px;
 color:#FFF;
 text-decoration:none;
 float:left;
 
 
}

#ul li a:hover{
 text-shadow:0px 0px 0px black,
    0px 0px 0px black,
    0px 0px 0px black,
    0px 0px 0px black; 
 font-size:19px;
    color:black;
}


.rodape {
 background: url(../imagens/rodape.png);
 width: 1056px;
 height: 99px;
 position:absolute;
 left:-3%;
 top:95%;

 
 
}
.local a{
 font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 19px;
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
 position:absolute;
 top: 9%;
 left: 4%;
 display:block;
 
}
 

.mapa1 a{
 font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
 position:absolute;
 left: 4%;
 top: 45%;
 display:block;
}

.facebook img{
 width: 32px;
 right: 32px;
 position:relative;
 top: 25px;
 left: 515px;
 opacity: 0.5;
 filter: alpha(opacity=50);
 
}

.facebook:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

.trabalhe h2{
 font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 19px;
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
 position: absolute;
 left: 842px;
 top: 15px;
 width: 159px;

}

.email1 {
 font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
 position:absolute;
 top: 35%;
 left:80%;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

form {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
 background-color:transparent;
    max-width: 500px;
 position:absolute;
 top:10%;
 left:4%;
 
 
}

h1 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 9px;
    color:#000;
 
    
}

input, textarea {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: black;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid;
 border-color:#CCC;
 margin:7px;
}

input:hover, textarea:hover, input:focus, textarea:focus {
    border-color:#000;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.submit input {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid;
 border-color:#CCC;
 background-color:#FFF;


}

.submit input:hover {
 border-color:#000;
    color: black;
}

textarea {
    width: 400px;
    height: 120px;
    line-height: 20px;
    max-width: 400px;
}

.whatsapp {
 position:absolute;
 right:48%;
 top:55%;
}

.outlook {
 position:absolute;
 right:48%;
 top:68%;
}

.numero {
 position:absolute;
 top:50.5%;
 right:20%;
 font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:20px;
 width:200px;
 height:50px;
}

.ig {
 position:absolute;
 top:62.5%;
 right:11%;
 font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:20px;
 width:300px;
 height:50px;
}

.ligue {
 position:absolute;
 top:78%;
 right:15%;
 font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:20px;
 width:300px;
 height:50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Alfatec</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="imagens/ico.png" type="imagem/x-png" />
<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link  href="css/estilofale.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.mask.min.js"/></script>
<style type="text/css">
body {
 background-image: url(imagens/projeto/imagens/fundo.jpg);
}
</style>

<script>
function Enviar() {

    var nome = document.getElementById("nomeid") ;

    if (nome.value != "") 
 
  {
        alert('Obrigado(a)  ' + nome.value +' os seus dados foram encaminhados com sucesso');
    }

}
</script>
</head>

<body>


<div id="topo"></div><!--div final topo-->
<div id="menufundo">

<nav id="ul">    
          <ul>            
           <li><a href="index.html" title="Página Inicial">Página Inicial</a></li> 
           <li><a href="quem_somos.html" title="Quem Somos">Quem Somos</a></li>
           <li><a href="cobertura.html" title="Áreas de Cobertura">Áreas de Cobertura</a></li> 
           <li><a href="servicos.html" title="Serviços">Serviços</a></li>
           <li><a href="fale_conosco.html" title="Fale Conosco">Fale Conosco</a></li>
       </ul>
</nav>
</div>

         
<div id ="fundoinicial">


    <div class="whatsapp">
                <img src="imagens/whatsapp-logo.png" />
                </div>
                
                <div class="outlook">
                <img src="imagens/icon.png" />
                </div>
                
                <div class="numero">
                <p class="numero" >94032-2448
                </p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="ig" >
                <p class="ig" >Afatecassist@ig.com.br</p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="ligue" >
                <p class="ligue" > Ou Ligue para 0800 580 2330</p>
                </div>

            <form name="meu_form" method="post" action="receba.php">
            
                    <h1>Entre em contato</h1>
            
                    <p class="nome">
                        <input type="text" id="nomeid" placeholder="Nome Completo"  required="required" name="nome" />
                    </p>
                    
                    <p class="fone">
        <input type="tel" name="txttelefone" id="txttelefone" pattern="\([0-9]{2}\)[\s][0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4,5}"               placeholder="Telefone" required="required" />
      <script type="text/javascript">$("#txttelefone").mask("(00) 0000-00009");</script>          
                    </p>
                    
                    <p class="email">
                       <input type="email"  id="email" value="" name="email" required="required" placeholder="Digite Seu E-mail"/>
                    </p>
                    
                    <p>
                       <textarea placeholder="Deixe sua Mensagem" required="required" name="mensagem"></textarea>
                    </p>
                    
                    <p class="submit">
                        <input type="submit" onclick="Enviar();" value="Enviar" />
                    </p>
            
            </form>

                                
 <div class="rodape">

    <div class="facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Alfatec-Autorizada-Electrolux-1737242946511224/" title=          "Facebook" target="_blank"><img src="imagens/facebook-logo (2).png" alt="FaceBook" width="42" class="facebook"      /></a>
                </div>


    <div class="local">
     <a class="local" " target="_blank" title="Abrir Mapa">Localização</a>
    </div>


    <div class="mapa1">
     <a href=
target="_blank" title="Abrir Mapa">R. Profᵃ José Azevedo Minhoto,          206<br/>
     Osasco - SP, 06080-125</a>
    </div>

    <div class="trabalhe" > 
      <h2>Trabalhe Conosco</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="email1" > 
      <p>rhalfatec@alfatec.com</p>
    </div>
    
    
             
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Está utilizando alguma linguagem *server-side*?

Comment: Não , tenho um host grátis apenas para testes

Comment: No seguinte trecho: `<form name="meu_form" method="post" action="receba.php">` , você está apontando o seu formulário para o arquivo `receba.php`. O que você programou neste arquivo?

Comment: Esse arquivo "receba.php" esta em branco , por que não estou entendo como vou mandar as informações do meu formulário